# bash: propagating exit code of command executed in alias

Tags: bash, alias, exit-code

In bash, I'd like to propagate exit code of the particular command executed in alias, so that alias call itself would return it (exit with it).

Imagine the following example (Please note: command makes no sense, just demonstrates problem I face):

```
alias cda='cd \/a; exit_code=$?; echo "STATUS: $exit_code"; alias cdb='cd \/b'
cda && cdb
```

for me there are no such dirs as: `/a` and `/b` to make sure commands fail.
I'd like to execute `cdb` alias only in case `cda` alias execution succeeded. However, as `echo` was the last command and it ended with `exit` status `0` => both are executed

What I've tried is:

```
alias cda='cd \/a; exit_code=$?; echo "STATUS: $exit_code"; exit $exit_code'; alias cdb='cd \/b'
cda && cdb
```

however this exits the shell completely => not feasible for me.

Any idea how to propagate the exit status (in my case `$exit_code`) as the alias exit status?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's better that you just use functions over aliases:

```
cda() {
    cd /a
    exit_code=$?
    echo "STATUS: $exit_code"
    return "$exit_code" # optional
}

cdb() {
    cd /b
    exit_code=$?
    echo "STATUS: $exit_code"
    return "$exit_code" # optional
}
```

As for the alias you could try adding a test in the end:

```
alias cda='cd \/a; exit_code=$?; echo "STATUS: $exit_code"; [[ exit_code -eq 0 ]]'; alias cdb='cd \/b'
```

Comment: thanks for answer, that did it for me. the only question left is if it's achievable purely via alias or not.

Answer (score 1):

I have this a function in my `.bashrc`:

```
return_exitcode(){
    return $1
}
```

to simulate any required exit code (input checking is not done.).

With this, the alias would be:

```
alias cda='cd /a; exit_code=$?; echo "STATUS: $exit_code"; return_exitcode $exit_code'
alias cdb='cd /b; exit_code=$?; echo "STATUS: $exit_code"; return_exitcode $exit_code'
```

NOTEs:

1. **Using functions is ALWAYS preferred over aliases.** Hence konsolebox's answer is the correct answer.
2. This answer was added just because this small function is sometimes handy, while writing commands after one another with `;`...